# Change the buffer a Float64Array is being used to view?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, typed-arrays

Take the following code:

```
var firstbuffer = new ArrayBuffer(128);
var secondbuffer = new ArrayBuffer(128);

var onlyarray = new Float64Array(firstbuffer);
```

How could I make `onlyarray` be a view for `secondbuffer`, without creating a new array?

Comment: Sorry, you can't. The reference to the underlying buffer can't be changed after creation.

Comment: @Touffy I thought that might be the case.